# What is the concept of error bars in barplots in seaborn library?

Tags: visualization, data, seaborn

I am using seaborn library to perform EDA on a dataset having categorical variables. I am using barplot function and in that there are some black bars which I guess are error bars as I read in documentation. What do these error bars represent and how are they calculated ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears that even if you don't enter `ci` argument, it's set to `95` by default in [`barplot`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/fe172c44777f87159e9e2b00e919bbd055d6f696/seaborn/categorical.py) method, which gives you those error bars. If you don't want them, set `ci = None` while plotting. The bar is the confidence interval for the variable as the library describes, i.e. it's interval where the `95 %` of your variable lies in, which is estimated by [bootstrapping](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).